# SQL: How to select values from multiple tables that contains specified column

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to ask if someone know how to get all values from multiple tables which have the specified column.

For example I have five tables (t1 ... t5) but only t2, t3, t4 contains column 'a' - how I get all values of 'a' if I don't know which tables contains it?

I would like solution primarily for MySQL (but also for PostgreSQL).

Thanks.

Comment: Doing this requires dynamic SQL, which is quite dependent on the database that you are using.

Comment: I need solution for postgresql primarily but if someone know solution for mysql I would be happy too.

Answer (score 0):

This should find all the columns on the SQL server. Just set the Column name in the first commented area.

Test the test me area.

Then use the comments below to switch from printing the query and executing the query.

```
 declare @tab table (id int identity(1,1) primary KEY
 ,TABLE_CATALOG varchar(50)
 ,TABLE_SCHEMA varchar(50)
 ,TABLE_NAME varchar(50)
 ,COLUMN_NAME varchar(50))
insert into @tab(TABLE_CATALOG ,
        TABLE_SCHEMA ,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME)
-------    Test me
SELECT  TABLE_CATALOG ,
        TABLE_SCHEMA ,
        TABLE_NAME,
        COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
-- Set the Column Name you are looking for.
WHERE   COLUMN_NAME = 'name'
----
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
---- Test me endline

declare @sql varchar(8000), @i int,@count INT
, @TABLE_CATALOG varchar(50)
,@TABLE_SCHEMA varchar(50)
,@TABLE_NAME varchar(50) 
,@COLUMN_NAME varchar(50) 

set @i=1
select @count= count(*) from @tab
while @i <= @count

begin
select @TABLE_CATALOG=TABLE_CATALOG
,@TABLE_SCHEMA=TABLE_SCHEMA
,@TABLE_NAME=TABLE_NAME
,@COLUMN_NAME=COLUMN_NAME
 from @tab where id=@i 

set @sql = '
  SELECT '+@COLUMN_NAME+' AS Column_Name,*
 FROM ['+@TABLE_CATALOG+'].['+@TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+@TABLE_NAME+']
'

--To Print the SQL Queries to the screen 
print @sql

-- Uncomment and comment the Print Above to excute them.
--exec (@sql)

set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - but this is PosgreSQL? Because on MySQL I got just error (I just copied you snippet to MySQl workbench and replace the column name)... thanks.

Comment: Or, please, write me how to use your snippet. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged sql not MySql totally different...which one is it?

Comment: Sorry, my fault - I changed tags.